# Need a way to do a "loop cut" on a triangle fan

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Need a way to do a loopcut- ish thingy on the blue line

[image]

Comment: Please accept an answer if it resolved the question. And I think that @gandalf3's answer is the best.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way is to use vertex bevel (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>):

[image]

Once the triangle fan is converted to quads you can add loopcuts. In the gif I converted the ngon resulting from the bevel to a triangle fan with *Poke* (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).

As an alternative to bevel, you might also try *Inset* (<kbd>I</kbd>):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

1. Select all the triangle fan edges in Edge Selection Mode.

[image]

2. Open Specials Menu using <kbd>W</kbd> button and select subdivide.
3. Hit <kbd>F6</kbd> button right after using Subdivide operation to open Subdivide Menu and adjust the number of subdivisions.

[image]

Or change the number of subdivisions in Subdivide Operator panel.

[image]

Comment: F6 isn't working for me - MacOS (BigSur) - 2.93