# Adding a loop cut between a vertex and edges on a sphere

Tags: modeling, uv

I have a UV Sphere projected at the pole and the UV to a single point smear issue

[image: The issue]

I read that this is because blender does not properly map the triangles at the poles. I found that I can "fix" the UV vertices (ouch):

[image: enter fix]
[image: enter result]

Or, perhaps a much easier way is to add a loop cut close to the pole to the VU has a quad instead of a trip to work with. The issue that I an having is; if I try and add a loop cut I can't seem get it to show up between the last edge loop and the pole.

For example I want to to place a loop cut where the arrow is:
[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Edit geometry there a bit, like beveling that vertex or alike.. If your quesiton is about adding loopcut between triangle fan and edge loop then see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33501/need-a-way-to-do-a-loop-cut-on-a-triangle-fan

Comment: Vertex Bevel! i knew there must have been a way to skin that cat. Thanks! now do I mark my own question as a dup :)