# Why the subsurf and smooth are not working in my model?

Tags: modeling

I try to smooth my model. I have tried with Surb surf and Smooth in Modifier but nothing.

[image]

Thank you so much

The ears are completed circle in Edit mode.
[image]

When I redered the ears are....
[image]
Why?

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe your heart mesh is missing some geometry, smoothing faces to the central vertex can't avoid those wrinkles... try adding a loop on the upper face.

Comment: Thank you. I did it. Do you think I can do something in the head?

Comment: The heart mesh needs more geometry, all of the edges are meeting in what is called a "triangle fan" or "pole". Please read this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47934/forcing-subdivide-to-create-non-zig-zag-edges/47938#47938

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33501/need-a-way-to-do-a-loop-cut-on-a-triangle-fan and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/fill-cylinder-cap-with-quads

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't fixed it yet. Edit mode the ears are perfect but when I redered they are not.  I attach the picture above. Many thanks